# Criando Scaffold Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Oi eu sou novo no Ruby on Rails. Eu estou tentando criar um pequeno site de blog. Eu tenho duas tabelas uma de  posts e outra de comentários. Cada Post terá muitos comentários, e terceira tabela será a de categorias queria saber como relacionar a tabela de categoria com a de posts, para cada post tem 1 categoria. Estou usando essa comando:

```
rails g scaffold Category name:string post:belongs_to
```

Porém o erro que me retorna quando eu gero essa tabela é:

> (1 error prohibited this category from being saved:)

Se alguém poder ajudar ficarei muito grato.

Answer (score 1):

A sua dúvida tem dois pontos que gostaria de comentar:

- O primeiro é em relação ao framework.
  Para gerar o relacionamento via scafold, se usa **modelo:references**. Nesse caso você geraria o scaffold da seguinte forma:

  rails g scaffold Category name:string post:references

O comando acima adiciona a chave de Posts em Category

E em category.rb adicionaria belongs_to :post

- O segundo ponto é e relação a modelagem. É claro que cada aplicação tem sua regra de negócio, mas acho que no seu caso seria melhor fazer o inverso, isto é, uma categoria ter vários posts, adicionando a chave da categoria no modelo Posts.